# TableLayoutPanel (C#). Eliminar margen que crea automáticamente

Tags: c#, visual-studio, interfaz-gráfica

Hoy tengo una duda al respecto de los TableLayoutPanel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Lo marcado en Rojo es el margen que se crea (y quiero eliminar).
- Lo azul forma parte del control que estoy añadiendo, y que debe permanecer así.

El problema está en que al añadir los controles de manera dinámica, siempre se crea este margen blanco en el lateral (apareciendo por consecuencia el Horizontal Scroll que se aprecia).

- Aspectos reseñables son que:

  - Si aumento el tamaño del Control de Usuario, el margen sigue apareciendo.
  - Si aumento el tamaño del TablePanel, el margen sigue apareciendo.
  - Si establezco el Dock como Fill al añadir el control, se rellena (deja de aparecer el margen), pero sigue apareciendo el scroll (al aumentar el panel o el control, siempre hace el margen y me lo rellena).
  - Si pongo el panel en AutoSize, me deja de aparecer el Scroll (aunque supere el tamaño).
  - Si pongo el control en Autosize, el margen sigue apareciendo (y de hecho, me corta parte de la barra azul).

Directamente quiero que no aparezca.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Has intentado usar `DockStyle.Fill` para los cuadros de Texto y colocar el `Margin = new Padding(0);` ?

Comment: @J.Rodríguez ha sido lo primero que he probado, ya que lo he visto, pero nada. No funciona como debería

Comment: Cómo tienes configurado el estilo (Size) de las columnas?, puede que [este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34479218/8933039) te de una idea para resolver el problema.